# How to split a word in JSTL?

Tags: jstl

For example, my string is `INWORK`. I want to split that string into `IN` ad `WORK`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JSTL EL functions to get a substring:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

${fn:substring('INWORK', 0, 2)}
${fn:substring('INWORK', 2, 6)}
```